# I can't import .cls file into my project. .cls file imported as Modules. How can I import .cls file as Class?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, class, import

I'm using Excel version 16.31, the latest version of Excel for Mac. 
I'm a newbie on VBA, and so the first time I exported Class Modules and tried import .cls file into my project again to see how it goes. And my expectation was that **.cls** file would be imported as **Class**, however actually was imported as a **Module**. Also my understanding is that only importing **.bas** file should be imported as **Module**, and when importing "**Sheet Module**" and "**Book Module**", they will be imported as **Class** despite of our desires. The results of importing all these .cls files were imported as **Modules**.
 
Is this just a glitch or the default? If it's the default, then how can I import these files as I intend? Copy & Paste won't work for me since I'd like to set **Attribute** for variables in **Class**, such as *Attribute variableName.VB_VarDescription*, which won't be achieved by Copy & Paste.

Comment: I'm not seeing any problems with exporting then importing class modules, whether a "custom" class or a Sheet class. You do have to be careful, however, that the names are unique. Although in my test VB renamed the imported class to differentiate it. Also note that a Sheet class will *not* create a new Sheet object in the workbook - it will be imported as any other class.

Comment: @MatWatershed If there are any compilation errors that weren't resolved before exporting the class, then when you import it, it will default to a `.bas` file, i.e. standard module. You need to post an example of the class right after you export it, and then post what it looks like after you have made your edits to give you an exact answer though. As @CindyMeister said, dealing with `Sheet` modules or the `ThisWorkBook` module is different all together.

Comment: @CindyMeister, @rickmanalexander Thank you for your advices. In the exported  `.cls` file, I had an error made when I coded attributes on variables, which led the issue like @rickmanalexander said `.cls` imported as `.bas`. But now I had  an another problem that although I wrote a line  `Attribute procName.VB_Description = "~~"`, the description doesn't show up on Object Browser...